# How to resolve PHP Mailer mail not sending error

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

we are facing issue with PHP Mailer $mail->send() function. No mails are triggered

### Configuration

PHM Mailer - 6.2.0
PHP Version - 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18

### Error Received

{
"usage_tracked": "metric already tracked for today",
"message": "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting%22),
"status": 0
}

above mailerbelow mailer2023-04-21 09: 38: 37 Connection: opening to ssl:
//send.smtp.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (  'ssl' =>   array (    'verify_peer' => false,    'verify_peer_name' => false,    'allow_self_signed' => true,  ),)

2023-04-21 09: 39: 17 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL: Success [/var/www/html/production-api/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 375
]

2023-04-21 09: 39: 17 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/var/www/html/production-api/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 375]

2023-04-21 09: 39: 17 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl: //send.smtp.com:465 (Unknown error) [/var/www/html/production-api/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 375]

2023-04-21 09: 39: 17 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)

SMTP connect() failed. https: //github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

We have an API to raise queries. Once the API is hit we are doing some SQL operations like inserting the user query to db. Once everything is done, we are sending a mail to admin and user with a notification and thank you mail respectively

Comment: It looks like your server does not have openssl configured properly. It won't help that you're using an old version of PHPMailer, and also an old (and unsupported) version of PHP.